# AngularJS - Redirect after login not working

Tags: angularjs

After a user successfully logs in i would like the page to redirect to the homepage. My code currently looks like:

```
function MainCtrl(user, auth) {
  var self = this;

  function handleRequest(res) {
    var token = res.data ? res.data.token : null;
    if(token) { $location.path('/'); }
    self.message = res.data.message;
  }

  self.login = function() {
    user.login(self.username, self.password)
      .then(handleRequest, handleRequest)
  }

}
```

Why does the line `$location.path('/');` not work, is that where i should actually have the redirect?

And the route config part:

```
.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/home.html"
    }
  )
  .when("/login",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/login.html"
    }
  )
  .when("/register",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/register.html"
    }
  );
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your route config part

Comment: which page you want to open after login? home isn't it?

Comment: Yes thats right, home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to inject **[`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)** in your controller

Try like this

```
function MainCtrl(user, auth,$location) {
```